# mysql php sort by highest of 3 separate fields

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a table with 3 separate scores in 3 separate fields:

```
User / Score 1 / Score 2 / Score 3
Person 1: 10 21 7
Person 2: 17 4 20
Person 3: 1 5 22
```

Is there a mysql command that will effectively sort each person out by the highest score from the 3 fields.

So here I need it to return:

```
Person 3: 1 5 22
Person 1: 10 21 8
Person 2: 17 4 20
```

The only way I can think of doing it would be to put them in an array, check each number for each person against each other to find the highest, then sort them into a different array.

This seems very long-winded and labour intensive though.

Comment: i think based on sum of scores you decided here your expected output? isn't it?

Comment: How is your expected output sorted by the highest score?

Comment: How is this a MySQL question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `order by greatest(score1,score2,score3) desc`

Manual for [GREATEST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)

Comment: Looks excellent to me. I didn't even know the command 'greatest' existed!